# Python: Can you upload a .xlsx file from xlsxwriter without creating one locally?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I hope this question is as straightforward as I think it is.

Here is some background:

I'm helping out on python backend that is getting messy data as a csv. In its current state it just reroutes the url given by the API and triggers a download on the client computer.  I wrote a utility using Pandas and xlsxwriter that cleans up this data, separates into multiple tabs and makes some graphs then writes them to a .xlsx file. Basically like this:

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_name, engine = 'xlsxwriter')

#Do a bunch of stuff and save each tab to writer

writer.save() #Writes the file
```

This .xlsx file would be created locally and there would need to be additional backend stuff that uploads it and cleans up the local file.

Seeing as the file is created all at once using the .save() method at the end, I was thinking its probably possible to trigger an upload directly without creating the local file at all, but I'm not seeing anything in xlsxwriter documentation about it.  Is there any way to avoid saving a local file within or outside of xlsxwriter?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe variable:

```
import io

buffer = io.BytesIO()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(buffer, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
data = buffer.getvalue()
```

`data` contains the binary data of excel file. For instance, you can use `requests` module to upload file somewhere.

Comment: Where is 'output' coming from in 'data = output.getvalue()'?